# Get macro value from NSString containing macro name

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, c-preprocessor

I have an array full of `#define` macros values. I have also a plist file (dictionary) with dictionaries, each named the same as the `#define` macros name. I get the the names of the dictionaries from the plist files and have them in NSString. Now, I need to convert the string (equal to the name of a macro) to the actual macro value. Then I need to compare the array full of the values against the values of the macros specified in the .plist file and check if it is equal. See code for example.

How can I do that?

```
    #define ACHIEVEMENT1_ID (ISIPAD() ? @"com.company.blablaHD.id" : @"com.company.blabla.id")
    #define ACHIEVEMENT2_ID ....
    ......

    - (void)checkPlistAndKnownIdentifiers:(NSDictionary *)_plistDictionary {

        NSArray *_knownIdentifiers = @[ACHIEVEMENT1_ID, ACHIEVEMENT2_ID, ...];

        NSArray *_plistDictionariesNames = [_plistDictionary allKeys];

        for (int idx = 0; idx < [_knownIdentifiers count]; idx++) {

           if (_knownIdentifiers[idx] == _plistDictionariesNames[idx]){
               // _knownIdentifiers[idx] returns @"com.company.blabla.id", for example
               // but _plistDictionariesNames[idx] returns @"ACHIEVEMENT1_ID", that is the problem
           } else {
               assert(NO);
           }

        }

    }
```

There might be some errors, as I am writing this from memory, but you should get the general idea.

Also, I don't want to use extern const strings here, so that's the reason I am asking for help :)

Comment: Is there a reason not to use const strings instead ? Because it sounds much more proper to me ...

Comment: Yes, there is - because I need to set different IDs for those strings depending on if it's iPhone or iPad. I found a different way on how to do it, I instead created two .plist for both devices and put there the macro values (instead of macro names) as names of the dictionaries, so when comparing, I compare values and everything works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question; you want to be able to use a macro name at run time.
This is actually impossible, as preprocessor compute the macro, and replace it before actual compilation.
Your macro name does not exist anymore at runtime